# Lambda functions cause race condition for shared access token | Serverless Framework | Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, serverless-framework, race-condition

I have a lambda nodejs function that basically forwards requests to a third-party resource server, this third-party server requires an access token that is generated on my backend and appended to the request (Axios). Only the latest issued token works and the previously generated token becomes invalid once a new one is issued.

Problem: If two or more requests are received on the backend at the same time calling said function, one of the two requests will have a race condition and result in usage of an invalid access token

Using Serverless framework (AWS) with Nodejs.
Correct me if I'm wrong but there is no way to share a variable like in the express framework since each function request is completely separate.
Should I store the token in a database? (A solution I don't personally like)
I also assume caching has no meaning for sls functions.

Any suggestions/solutions are appreciated.

Note: Multiple other functions use the flow for the same resource server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want all of your requests to be processed sequentially. In that case, you can set a [maximum concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) to 1, and you won't have two lambdas running at the same time

That being said, it won't scale anymore and it kinda defeats the benefits of a serverless infrastructure.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to prevent that. Keep in mind multiple functions will use the same flow, so Its not a single function issue.
Even with a DB I believe a race condition will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is stateless compute, so if you need shared state, you'll need to build that. If your throughput is low, dynamo is cheap enough and comes with consistency guarantees that may be effective for you.

If not, redis would be a good option, especially a managed a managed solution like [redislabs](https://redislabs.com/) which offers an HTTP API, nicely suited for Lambda.